# Can import tensorflow CPU-only but not with GPU activated into python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tensorflow

Importing tensorflow into python with only the CPU activated works fine, but trying to import the GPU-activated version into python results in the following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>  
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>  
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-  packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in   swig_import_helper  
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow')  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module  
    __import__(name)  
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow
```

Comment: Try posting on the GitHub issues page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues